# Jquery populate select field with option from json array

Tags: jquery, json

I have a php script that returned a json array similiar to this

```
var option = '[{"mod":"Width","values":{"field":"A","value":"96}},
{"mod":"Height","values":{"field":"B","value":"33}}]';
```

My javascript looks like this

```
$.each(option.values, function(i, vi) {

  $('#mod).html($.map(option.values, function (v) {
    return $('<option>', {
      value: v.value,
      text: v.value,
      'data-field': v.field,
      'data-valeur': v.value,


  })).prop('disabled', false).trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

I get a console error saying: ***TypeError: v is null***

Can anyone tell me what is happenins.
[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/podu81Lj/2/)

Comment: json is not valid .

Comment: Valid json:[{"mod":"Width","values":{"field":"A","value":"96"}},
{"mod":"Height","values":{"field":"B","value":"33"}}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please Validate your JSON then use there is some missing quotations are there

for refrence https://plnkr.co/edit/FxqwzQnItGwaswVzmBir

**JS**

```
var option = [
    {
        "mod": "Width",
        "values": {
            "field": "A",
            "value": "96"
        }
    },
    {
        "mod": "Height",
        "values": {
            "field": "B",
            "value": "33"
        }
    }
]

$("#mod").append($.map(option, function(o) {
  return $('<option/>', {
    value: o.values.value,
    text: o.values.field
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a valid JSON. Even after you get a valid JSON, you have to **parse** it like this:

```
// Get an object from a valid JSON string
var obj = JSON.parse(option);

// Loop through this object
for(var o in option) {
   ...
}
```

Check [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) in order to validate JSON

Answer (score 0):

You need the following changes,

```
var option = [{
  "mod": "Width",
  "values": {
    "field": "A",
    "value": 96
  }
}, {
  "mod": "Height",
  "values": {
    "field": "B",
    "value": 33
  }
}];

$("#mod").append($.map(option, function(v) {
  return $('<option/>', {
    value: v.values.value,
    text: v.values.value
  });
}));
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6366/)